# Confused with this Salesforce recruiting app question

Tags: custom-object, setup, authorization

I don't want the answer to this question but I just want someone to guide me the right way.

Following is the question...
[image]

My question is..

Where is the clue in the question for me to understand that I, as developer, have to choose look-up relationship for this situation? As far as my knowledge is concerned, in look-up relationships, if we delete the parent, there is no effect on child.

[PS: I was asked by an admin not to post certification question. I respect that. I suppose this is the right way to ask.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read once again information about master-detail relationship.

try here

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/relationships_among_objects.htm

here is some tip:
check sharing and security :)

Comment: @artur-kepczynski.. Thanks for the tip. But still not able to figure out.

Comment: `The detail record inherits the sharing and security settings of its master record.` is it now clear?

Comment: THnx for the info!

Answer (score 3):

First thing you can identify is the OWD setting for the objects, using the most restricted user in the requirement. Then try to eliminate the options which does not fit OWD setting.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Lookups relationships can be set to cascade delete.

For a ton of information about the different types of relationships in Salesforce, read this help article: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm&language=en_US